# Query with composite PK collection via spring data (Hibernate JPA)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have entity class User with composite key via @IdClass annotation

```
@Entity
@IdClass(UserId.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    private String name;

    @Id
    private String surname;

    private boolean active;

}
```

Composite key:

```
@Data
public class UserId implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
}
```

I use Spring Data with hibernate JPA under hood. Therefore I have repo interface:

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, UserId> {

}
```

And I'd like to get all active users from db by list of concrete names and surnames. 
E.g. I'd like to use method like this

```
List<User> findAllByActiveTrue(List<UserId> ids);
```

How can I do query for this requirement via Spring Data or JPQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Embeddable` & `@EmbeddedId` for composite primary key

```
@Embeddable
public class UserId implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
}

@Entity
public class User {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserId userId;
    ...
}
```

Then query like

```
List<User> findByUserIdInAndActiveTrue(List<UserId> ids);
```

A good tutorial about `@Embeddable` & `@EmbeddedId` [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-embedded-method-parameters)

Comment: Thank you! It really works well! Just for information, can I do something like that via @IdClass? Or is it fundamentally impossible?

Comment: @Kitovsky I don't think it's possible to query like you tried with `@IdClass`. If you do raw query  then possible it think.